# Use Java API to populate a Google Chart

Tags: java, javascript, web-applications, real-time, google-visualization

I have to use [a Java API](http://www.dataturbine.org/sites/default/files/programs/RBNB/doc/com/rbnb/sapi/Sink.html) to get data from a server. I need to use this data to populate a real-time chart ([annotated timeline](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline)). We want to use the Google Charts API, written in javascript.

Does anyone have a good resource for connecting these two languages? Again, we want a webpage that uses javascript to pull data from a java source.

Comment: What about using a servlet to handle the data retrieval? Couple that with a webpage that uses AJAX to create/populate charts using the retrieved data.

Comment: @Creakazoid If you expand on that a bit (perhaps add a few basic examples) and make it an answer, I'd upvote it.

Comment: @Creakazoid that sounds awesome. how might the servlet part look? right now I'm trying to put my data into a JSON and send that to the front end.